# Sharing httpsession between themes and portlet in different portlet application

Tags: java, servlets, liferay, portlet, httpsession

I am trying to share the httpsession between themes and portlet in different portlet application. But it always return null value in the portlet.

The themes is posting in to a servlet to store httpsession :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("testsession", "testsession");
```

and i tried to retrieve the session in portlet with following ways:

1)

```
HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);
System.out.println("session "+session.getAttribute("testsession"));
```

2)

```
System.out.println("portletsession :"+renderRequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute("testsession", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE));
```

3)

```
HttpSession httpSession = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest).getSession(false);
         System.out.println("httpSession 212 in java : "+httpSession.getAttribute("testsession"));
```

All of the above return null. Does anyone have experience in
 implementing this behaviour before ?

Thanks,

Cyril

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work in the private-session-attributes tag. However my solution for this is to embed the portlet into the themes via the portlet instances id.

Here for further information :

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Embedding+a+portlet+in+the+theme

Thanks

Comment: PLease also include some of details in your answer section

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this attribute in `liferay-portlet.xml`

```
<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
```

HTH